# add column to dataframe with sequence of integers depending on another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,5,2,5,4,2,5,2,3,1,4,1], 'B':['x','y','x','x','y','z','z','x','y','y','x','z']})
```

I'd like to add a column `C` that, for each letter in `B`, contains sequential integers:

```
    A  B  C
0   3  x  1
1   5  y  1
2   2  x  2
3   5  x  3
4   4  y  2
5   2  z  1
6   5  z  2
7   2  x  4
8   3  y  3
9   1  y  4
10  4  x  5
11  1  z  3
```

Comment: must be a dup: `df['C'] = df.groupby('B').cumcount() + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumcount()` grouping by B

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,5,2,5,4,2,5,2,3,1,4,1], 'B':['x','y','x','x','y','z','z','x','y','y','x','z']})
df['C'] = df.groupby('B').cumcount() + 1
```